# Validation of radio button in cakephp

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to validate radio button, when i checked radio button textbox will be disabled,
but it cant happens.
what will be the exact js for validate radio button.

My JS code is :

function selection_project_phd()
  {
     var phds  = document.getElementById('EmployeeGuidedProjectPhd').value;
     var projs  = document.getElementById('EmployeeGuidedProjectProject').value;
     var course_name  = document.getElementById('EmployeeGuidedProjectCourseName').value;

     if(phds == 1)
      {   
          course_name.disable=true;
      return false;
      }
     else
      if(projs==0)
       {
      course_name.disable=false;
      return false;
       }
    return true;
  }

This one is View file .ctp code

Phd 
    Project

Answer (score 3):

```
function selection_project_phd() { 
    var phds = document.getElementById('EmployeeGuidedProjectPhd').checked; 
    var projs = document.getElementById('EmployeeGuidedProjectProject').checked; 
    var course_name = document.getElementById('EmployeeGuidedProjectCourseName'); 
    if(phds) { course_name.disable=true; return false; } 
    else if(projs !== true ) { course_name.disable=false; return false; } 
    return true;  
}
```

Comment: you might want to vote up and accept the answer :) Welcome to Stack overflow !